# Redirect when the site's home is set to a page

Tags: home-url

Is it possible to have Wordpress display the full URL string when a specific page listed more than one level deep is set up as the home page under Reading settings?

If I have example.com/parent/child set up as the home page under WP, I want that full string displayed in the browser, not just example.com.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nested child page to load when the home page is called, I would set up a separate page as your home page. Create a custom template for that page. Then setup a redirect in the template file for the home page.

You would then setup your placeholder page as the home page from the Settings->Reading menu.

So for example, first I would create a new template file that looks something like this:

```
<?php
// Template Name: Redirector

$redirect = get_bloginfo('url').'http://www.example.com/parent/child/'
wp_redirect($redirect);
exit;

?>
```

I would then create a new page. Name it 'Redirector' or whatever and then select the "Redirector" page template from the template drop down menu, which should be available on the page editor in the far right column.

Then you'll need to select the "Redirector" page as your home page from the Settings->Reading menu. Select "Static Page" and then select "Redirector" as your Front Page option from the drop down menu.

Comment: Thank you, Brent. Is this SEO friendly? Will there be 301 or 302s in the logs?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly sure what kind of effect it would have on SEO. I don't think this is being treated as 301 redirect, though I'm a little rusty on the subject. The redirect that Wordpress performs are PHP redirects, not HTACCESS redirects.

Comment: TIL - the wp_redirect docs let you specifiy 301 or 302 as optional second argument.